# How to share data between replicas of microservice dynamically without restarting application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I have a microservice on kubernetes. It is scaled up to 4 pods. I have created one Object to set some value dynamically using rest api.but that object will be updated on single pod by rest api. I have to share same value on 3 more pods with single URL at same time without restarting application.

*I was thinking hazelcast for this requirement but it require admin privileges which i can not provide.*

Error

```
{"date":"2019-03-19T08:30:32.920+00:00","loglevel":"ERROR","logger_name":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner","thread_name":"main","message":"[10.128.10.37]:5701 [some-group] [3.10.2] Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/somespace/endpoints/some-service . Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. endpoints \"some-service\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:some-test:default\" cannot get endpoints in the namespace \"somespace\": User \"system:serviceaccount:some-test:default\" cannot get endpoints in project \"somespace\".","stack_trace":"io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/gaming/endpoints/some-service . Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. endpoints \"some-service\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:some-test:default\" cannot get endpoints in the namespace \"gaming\": User \"system:serviceaccount:some-test:default\" cannot get endpoints in project \"gaming\".\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:470)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:407)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:379)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:343)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:312)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:295)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:787)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:217)\n\tat io.fabric8.kubernetes.client
```

Comment: You can describe `URL` how `ENV` variable and use ConfigMap: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: @Arslanbekov yes we can but i have to set this value dynamically. updated question.

Comment: Maybe this help you? https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes has support for reloading properties from config maps. Regarding hazelcast what admin privileges does it require that you don't have?

Comment: @Arslanbekov reloader require application restart

Comment: @Mark i created rbrc.yaml which require admin permission to apply.

Comment: Also you can try Spring Cloud Config Server - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html, this also lets you also define how often you want your data to be refreshed

Comment: @fatcook yes its good but i not wanted dependency on particular module (config).